# Ongoing Edmac question

Tags: edmac

Belated thanks to those who answered my initial query on this last October - for some reason I didn't get the info that anyone had responded.  There still may not be a solution, but as I've had a sample to tinker with, here goes.  This PDF:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3q6hty7cuaaguibgappib/EETS_SAMPLE.pdf?rlkey=q1u2nezhqx0z15ztaypvgy665&dl=1

shows two pages of the same text done in Edmac in plain XeTeX.  The first page is how it would paginate normally, and the second page (envisaged as an interim stage in a complicated job) was meant to show a page with the app. crit. doubled up (it does) and therefore allowing more of the main text plus app. crit. to appear on the same page (it doesn't!).  All it does is to break pages at exactly the same point, halving the vertical size of the app. crit. area but not allowing any more text or app. crit. in.  I achieved the bunching up by tinkering with \normalbaselines but have not managed to figure out how to influence Edmac's calculation as to what it can fit on the page.  I can't immediately see where it does this (and am not sure I even grasp where plain TeX does this). Any help would be appreciated!  John

Comment: please do not use external links. Your question will be archived here forever and not make sense if that dropbox link goes stale. also give a link to your earlier question, don't make people search the site to find the context.

Comment: This seems to be an exact duplicate of your previous question, you should edit that not add a new one.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate - I made some progress on my own as per the PDF I included yesterday (8 Jan. 2024).  I can make further progress if someone can help me work out how to influence the way that Edmac (or even TeX) determines the amount of footnote material that can be fitted on a page.  When I halved the interlinear leading of the apparatus I assumed (wrongly) that this would change the number of lines of main text and apparatus that appeared on the page, but all that has happened is that I get bunched-up apparatus but exactly the same page breaks.

Comment: you could still update the original unanswered question as how could anyone answer the original question if you post a new version elsewhere? please don't leave old unanswered questions and don't use external links. as you see in your last question, those dropbox links do break and leave the question as unintelligable.